# Websocket connection in case of browser crash

Tags: websocket, netty

Pardon me if the question is simple , but I don't know what will happen in this **general scenario** : If due to some issue or failure / system failure (any kind of failure , etc) the browser crashes , what will happen to a websocket connection that was running ? Will it be closed or what will be its state ?

I am using netty websocket implementation.  Now , specifically in **netty websocket implementation** , in the above scenario , what would happen ? (When I tried , I get this : if I close the browser manually , the connection is closed but if I kill the browser process , this does not happen). If the connection is not closed , how can I detect it / handle it while sending messages , otherwise while sending messages , a `ClosedChannelException` occurs when trying to send a message.

EDIT : Apart from checking for the above mentioned error , is there a way of knowing that the websocket connection has been closed when using the netty implementation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll have to catch ClosedChannelException and handle that in the same way you would for a connection that was cleanly closed.

If your websocket sessions are expensive and you want to spot killed connections more quickly, you could periodically send a [ping](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.2) request to each client.  Netty has a PingWebSocketFrame class which looks like it'd support this for you.

Comment: The first alternative seems fine , but the second option, hmm... I am using websockets so that I won's have to unnecessarily ping periodically (also an advantage of websockets) and the reason for trying to spot killed connections is due to the fact that the exception is thrown up.

Comment: @shg Periodic pings are not necessary.  I only included them as an option in case you were unable to wait for a ClosedChannelException to spot a killed connection.